# Cannot install Nvidia driver X server

Tags: ubuntu, nvidia-graphics-card

I downloaded `NVIDIA-Linux-x86-295.59.run` from the official Nvidia website, I used in the terminal `sudo sh NVIDIA-Linux-x86-295.59.run` the installation started and everything, but I got this

```
ERROR: You appear to be running an X server; please exit X before            
         installing.  For further details, please see the section INSTALLING   
         THE NVIDIA DRIVER in the README available on the Linux driver         
         download page at www.nvidia.com.
```

I'm a newbie to ubuntu, and I don't know so much codes, can you please tell me step by step?

Answer (score 2):

The recommended way to install nVidia drivers on ubuntu can be found [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/Nvidia), namely:

1. Go to `System` -> `Administration` -> `Additional Drivers` and select the nvidia (current) driver to install.
2. Reboot your machine.

If you're installing from the command line, the recommended way is:

```
jockey-text --help
jockey-text -l
jockey-text -e xorg:nvidia_current
```

---

The issue you're seeing is that you're trying to update or install the nVidia drivers using the nVidia-official package while the display server ("X" or "X.org") is running. You need to shut down the X server and switch to one of the console terminals in order to install it. This does get a bit advanced, which is why I suggest one of the above methods which should make it a bit more straight-forward, but if you want to get your hands dirty then enjoy going the manual route and learning about how the X server functions/works. I've not done a manual installation of the drivers in recent years, so I can't remember if you have to recompile the kernel or obtain the kernel headers.